# merging two datagridview columns into one new column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i want to merge two datagridview columns into one new column.

i first change Visible property of two col to false, then i try to add new col which that value must be formatted as this which col1Value and col2Value is value of above columns:

```
string.Format("{0} per {1}", col1Value, col2Value);
```

my code

```
reportResultForm.dgvResult.Columns["Height"].Visible = false;
reportResultForm.dgvResult.Columns["Width"].Visible = false;
DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "{0} per {1}";
col.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
dgvResult.Columns.Add(col);
```

but i dont know how do this! please help me. my way is true?

Comment: How do you expect to merge two columns into one column? The data is different and so how are you going to handle the different data?

Comment: i want to use value of col1 and col2 to show thats in newcol with top format.

newcolValue = string.Format("{0} per {1}", col1Value, col2Value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can made your own implementation of the DataGridViewTextBoxCell and override GetFormattedValue method for it. There you can return the formatted value for your column below is an example:

```
// use custom DataGridViewTextBoxCell as columns's template
col.CellTemplate = new MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

...

```
// custom DataGridViewTextBoxCell implementation 
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override Object GetFormattedValue(Object value,
        int rowIndex,
        ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
        TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} per {1}",
            this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value,
            this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it works for me):

```
reportResultForm.dgvResult.Columns.Add("newColumn", "New Column");
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in reportResultForm.dgvResult.Rows)
        {
            string height= row.Cells["Height"].Value.ToString();
            string width= row.Cells["Width"].Value.ToString();
            string formattedCol= string.Format("{0} per {1}", height, width);
            row.Cells["newColumn"].Value = formattedCol;
        }
```